# How to show image editing controls in iPhone camera programatically

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5

I have been working one app that includes iPhone camera and photo gallery. I have a thought of doing some functionalities for my app like cropping and rotating. I have searched in web for somethings related to Apple did.

But I am unable to get the proper information related to that. I am not sure whether the possibility is there or not to do something like when we select an image from gallery and click on edit button Apple directly showing image edit controls like crop brightness and rotation. If I want to implement the same in my app is it possible or I need to go for the third party controls. Here is the image to show toy you to exactly get my point how I need controls in camera.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can enable image editing features of UIImagePickerController by calling

```
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];// imagePicker is UIImagePickerController instance
```

And later access your edited picture by UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage key.

If you want to provide editing features separate from UIImagePickerController you have to either implement them yourself or use some third-party solution. For example [this open source library](https://github.com/heitorfr/ios-image-editor)

Comment: Thats good answer but it doesn't suits to this I think. I have already tried with above solution but it shows only crop.But if you see in above pic it shows complete image controls like crop,rotate,brightness. if we have a thought to implement the same is it possible..?